# Calculating Spiral Capacitor Capacitance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, capacitance

I had to calculate capacitance of two flat plates with width $a$ length $l$ and distance between them $d<<R$ where $R$ is the radius of spiral in which those two plates were rolled into. I tried this method: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi } \frac{1}{2} R^2 d\theta  * E = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0} \\ \\ \\ \\ E = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\pi R^2 \epsilon_0} \\ \Delta V=-\int{}E dx \\ C=\frac{Q_{enc}}{\Delta V}$$ now this is obviously wrong, but other methods are too long to write here. answer given in the book is : $$C=\frac{\epsilon_0 al}{d} \left( 1+\frac{ld}{2\pi R^2}\right )$$